# Bounty reason in bounty tooltip?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I think it would be nice if the tooltip on an awarded bounty would also give the bounty reason given when offering the bounty.

Comment: That does sound like a nice (if somewhat undiscoverable) feature.

Comment: Once a bounty has been awarded, does it really matter why?

Comment: The main reason why that matters is "One of the answers is exemplary ...": It says that the bounty is awarded for the answer being exceptionally good (at least in the mind of the one awarding it), while "This question has not received sufficient attention" tells not much more about the quality of the answer than being accepted does.

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231217/if-an-answer-receives-a-bounty-the-bounty-reason-should-be-available-alongside ?

Comment: @Nemo: A question from April 2 is a dupe of a question from May 8 of the same year?

Comment: @celtschk, that question got slightly more activity and content, duping is not an accusation. :)